# Picard iterations to find $\dot{y}=\sqrt{y}$

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have to find the solution $y_n(t;0)$ of the differential equation of $\dot{y}=\sqrt{y}$ with $y(0)=0$ using the Picard iteration. Finding $y_1,y_2,...$ shouldn't be that hard. But I never find it easy to get the general $y_n(t;0)$. Can you tell me what it is for $y(0)=0$ and for $y(0)=\alpha$ with $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$?

P.S. I don't like the Picard iteration, I prefer Kirk ;)

Comment: Solution at $y(0)=0$ is not unique. There are two solutions $y=0$ and $y=\frac{1}{4}x^2$.

Comment: Take the initial $y(t)=0$ and you are done.

Comment: @A.G. Does the $y(t)=0$ also work with Picard?

Comment: @MrYouMath See comment above

Comment: @Barry_Allen Why not? There is no constraint on how to take the initial $y(t)$ other then $y(0)=0$ and differentiability. It is often taken as constant. Note though that if you take the initial function as $y(t)=t$, the iterations converge to another solution $x^2/4$. If the initial condition is $y(0)=\alpha>0$ then Picard-Lindelöf theorem gives uniqueness and guaranties convergence to the unique solution.